# Hashem "joins" a good thought to deed

Tags: talmud-gemara, thought

There's a famous saying (Kiddushin 40a) that Hashem treats a good intent as though it had been carried out:

> מחשבה טובה מצרפה למעשה

But מצרפה literally means "join," and I seem to recall an interpretation that Hashem helps bring a good thought to fruition. Is there an explanation like that somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's just a play on words but came across the following this week in explanation of Shemos 1:20

> וַיֵּיטֶב אֱלֹהִים לַמְיַלְּדֹת וַיִּרֶב הָעָם וַיַּעַצְמוּ מְאֹד.
>
> God dealt well with the midwives, and the nation multiplied and grew very mighty.

with הואיל משה explaining:

> וירב העם – מה היא הטובה? וירב העם, זה היה שכרם לראות שהיו סבה שירב העם ויעצמו, *ומחשבתם* *הטובה* *נצטרפה* *למעשה*.

Answer (score 1):

[Tanya (ch. 16)](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7895/jewish/Chapter-16.htm) explains it as follows:

> כִּי דְּחִילוּ וּרְחִימוּ שֶׁבְּהִתְגַּלּוּת לִבּוֹ, הֵם הַמִּתְלַבְּשִׁים בְּמַעֲשֵׂה הַמִּצְוֹת לְהַחֲיוֹתָם לְפָרְחָא לְעֵילָא, כִּי הַלֵּב הוּא גַּם כֵּן חוּמְרִי, כִּשְׁאָר אֵבָרִים שֶׁהֵם כְּלֵי הַמַּעֲשֶׂה, אֶלָּא שֶׁהוּא פְּנִימִי וְחַיּוּת לָהֶם, וְלָכֵן יָכוֹל לְהִתְלַבֵּשׁ בָּהֶם לִהְיוֹת לָהֶם גַּדְפִין לְהַעֲלוֹתָם. אַךְ הַדְּחִילוּ וּרְחִימוּ שֶׁבִּתְבוּנוֹת מוֹחוֹ וְתַעֲלוּמוֹת לִבּוֹ הַנִּזְכָּרוֹת לְעֵיל – גָּבְהוּ דַרְכֵיהֶם לְמַעְלָה מַּעְלָה מִבְּחִינַת הַמַּעֲשֶׂה, וְאִי אֶפְשָׁר לָהֶם לְהִתְלַבֵּשׁ בִּבְחִינַת מַעֲשֵׂה הַמִּצְוֹת לִהְיוֹת לָהֶם בְּחִינַת מוֹחִין וְחַיּוּת לְהַעֲלוֹתָן לְפָרְחָא לְעֵילָא, אִם לֹא שֶׁהַקָּדוֹשׁ־בָּרוּךְ־הוּא מְצָרְפָן וּמְחַבְּרָן לִבְחִינַת הַמַּעֲשֶׂה; וְהֵן נִקְרָאוֹת בְּשֵׁם "מַחֲשָׁבָה טוֹבָה", כִּי אֵינָן דְּחִילוּ וּרְחִימוּ מַמָּשׁ בְּהִתְגַּלּוּת לִבּוֹ, כִּי אִם בִּתְבוּנַת מוֹחוֹ וְתַעֲלוּמוֹת לִבּוֹ כַּנִּזְכָּר לְעֵיל

> It is the revealed fear and love of G‑d in the heart that vest themselves in one’s performance of the commandments, giving them vitality to soar on high, for the heart is also corporeal, like the other organs of the body which are the instruments of action. The heart is, however, internal and is the organs’ source of vitality. Therefore, because the heart, in its corporeality, is close to the other organs and also provides their vitality, it can clothe itself in their actions, to be their “wings,” elevating them. However, the abovementioned fear and love that are in the intelligence of the brain and the recesses of the heart are of a far higher order than the level of “action.” Therefore, they cannot clothe themselves in the performance of the commandments, to become their intellectual power and vitality, to elevate them so that they may soar on high—if not for the fact that G‑d **joins and unites them together with the action,** so that they may serve as its “wings.” They—the tevunah-fear and love—are called **“good thought,”** for they are not actual fear and love in a revealed state in the heart but only in the intelligence of the brain and the recesses of the heart, as mentioned above; since they express themselves in the mind, they are called “good thought.”

Answer (score 1):

This concept is spelled out in Sefer Hamaamarim 5702 [p. 87](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31682&st=&pgnum=92):

[image: Text]

> The true meaning of "joining to deed" is that when a Jewish person intends to do something with respect to Torah study, fulfillment of mitzvos or [attaining] good character traits, and he desires this with all his heart and might, Hashem arranges matters by divine providence so [his intention] comes to fruition.